# noCursorTimeout alternative for free atlas tier mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the mongo atlas tier, and I need to use  nocursortimeout (like collection.find(filter).noCursorTimeout(true)) but it seems to not be a thing for the free atlas tier. Are there any alternatives or is there a way around it?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what your use case is (basically why you think the noCursorTimeout is the solution) so that we can advise based on more complete context

Comment: try https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/#refresh-a-cursor-with-refreshsessions

Answer (score 1):

That is an intentional limitation in Atlas. From the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/backing-up-and-restoring-databases/):

> Free clusters and shared clusters can't use the noTimeout cursor option.

Using cursors with no timeout can increase resource usage on the server.  Since  free and shared tier clusters shard the same underlying machines with other Atlas users' clusters, it is reasonable to disallow actions that have a high probability of negatively impacting other users.

The direct workaround is use M10 or larger clusters, which don't restrict that option.

If you want help with how to rework your code so that you can get by without the noCursorTimeout option, you will need to show us the code.